# What type of bathroom sink supply plumbing is this?

Tags: plumbing, sink, plumbing-fixture

I'd like to replace the faucet (and add shut off valves below) but am unfamiliar with current piping beneath. I've done basic plumbing (valve to copper pipe via compression hookup) but these pipes don't look copper.

- what are these bends (can I connect water supply line without removing the joint?)
- are the pipes copper (coated with something) and/or are they compatible with copper fitting (can I replace the joint with quarter turn valve?)

The skinny pipe 3/8" the pipe from the wall is 5/8"

[image]

Comment: I've seen silver/chrome-colored "vanity" sleeves slid over copper/brass piping -- are these short horizontal outer sections from the wall attached to the pipe underneath, or can they be turned relative to it? If the latter, the bends are likely just elbows in function. In that case, yes you should be able to attach angle stops of the correct size threading.

Comment: The vertical skinny pipes look like older-style standard chrome-plated copper/brass water supply lines. I think that is just a standard compression nut connection to the bends.

Comment: Photos of the back side of the "bends" would help here.

Comment: Good idea to add valves but maybe unnecessary to remove those elbows.    I can't tell if they're soldered inside the wall, or threaded on the back side to the pipe emerging from the wall?  Easier: Existing plated copper tail is fitted to the elbows with compression fitting.    Buy inline quarter turn compression-to-X valve, where X is whatever your new faucet comes with, probably also compression.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Chrome-plated copper. They will last virtually forever, unlike "modern" flex lines. The fittings either are, or are compatible with, compression fittings.

The 5/8" pipe from the wall is almost certainly 1/2" (CTS) copper pipe, which has an OD of 5/8"